# Formation de "vibrocher"

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, verbes, littérature, néologismes

Dans sa préface de *Guignol's Band*, Céline emploie le verbe **vibrocher** : "Émouvez-vous bon Dieu ! Ratata ! Sautez ! **Vibrochez** ! Éclatez dans vos carapaces ! fouillez-vous crabes ! Éventrez ! Trouvez la palpite nom de foutre ! La fête est là ! Enfin ! Quelque chose ! Réveil ! Allez salut ! Robots la crotte ! Merde ! Transposez ou c'est la mort !"

Savez-vous, s'il vous plaît, quel est l'autre mot utilisé ici par Céline dans la formation de ce néologisme, en plus de "vibrer" ?

Answer (score 5):

*Vibrocher* est formé à partir de « vibrer ». Le mot ne se retrouve pas dans les dictionnaires et il est répertorié dans le [*carnet de grammaire n° 17*](http://w3.erss.univ-tlse2.fr/textes/publications/CarnetsGrammaire/carnGram17.pdf) <sup>*</sup> qui l'attribue à Céline. Ce carnet s'intéresse à la dérivation -Vche.

On peut lire :
« La dérivation en -Vche soulève peu de difficultés particulières du point de vue de la syntaxe et de la sémantique. Comme il est de règle avec les suffixes de sens « évaluatif », -Vche n'impose aucune condition sur la catégorie syntaxique de la base à laquelle il est ajouté, et le dérivé en -Vche hérite de cette catégorie [...] mais soulève de nombreux problèmes d'ordre phonologique.»
Selon ce rapport le suffixe -che est ajouté à la base verbale par concaténation.
Bien que ce mot ne se trouve pas dans les dictionnaires tout francophone le comprend facilement. L'ajout du suffixe -che peut avoir divers sens. Ici il pourrait évoquer une atténuation de l'action dont il est tiré, vibrer un peu, sans faire trop de bruit, (comme *vibroter*, qui serait aussi un néologisme, mais le suffixe -oter est perçu comme moins argotique).

<sup>*</sup> <sup>*Les Carnets de grammaire* est le nom d'une série de rapports de l'ERSS (Équipe de Recherche en Syntaxe et Sémantique de l'université Toulouse 2.</sup>

Comment: Je suppose qu'ici le V de -Vche désigne un «son vocalique». D'accord ça va directement dans le vif du sujet, mais pour quelqu'un comme moi qui n'a pas rencontré/étudié la notation auparavant, c'est un peu abrupt comme introduction. Ma première réaction a été qu'il y avait peut-être une erreur (ce que la suite a clairement démontré ne pas être le cas).

Comment: @Pasunclue Tu as raison, j'aurais dû le préciser pour ne pas obliger à se plonger dans l'article !

Comment: Il faut dire que l'article lui-même n'est pas plus explicite. La notation -Vche est directement introduite sans autre explication. C'est un peu -Vche de leur part!

Answer (score 2):

The answwer to your question is [here, (Wiktionnaire)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ocher).

> -ocher [prononcé comme "o chez", "hochet"]
> Suffixe verbal populaire à valeur dépréciative.
>
> Composés
>
> > balocher
> > bavardocher
> > bavocher
> > boulocher
> > branlocher
> > flânocher
> > garrocher
> > maillocher
> > mignocher
> > pétocher
> > pimprelocher
> > pleuvocher
> > rabibocher
> > râlocher
> > riocher

C'est un suffixe plus ou moins productif; on ne dira pas « mangeocher » mais on pourra dire , par example, « pattocher » (comme patouiller).